# Как расположить блоки div в несколько колонок?

Tags: css3, html, html5, css, вёрстка

Число блоков каждый раз разное, от 1 и до 40.
Нужно расположить их так:

```
1  7
2  8
3  9
4  ...
5
6
```

Число колонок может быть от 1 до 5. Сложность в том, что бы не используя скрипты, стандартным html+css добиться такого. 
Блоки разной высоты, и когда следующий блок не помещается снизу (высота контейнера 380px) начинаем новую колонку.

В html у меня это все вот так:

```
  <div class="test">                                       
    <a href="" class="c">Первый</a>
    <a href="" class="c">Второй</a>
    <a href="" class="c">Третий</a>
    <a href="" class="c">Четвертый</a>
    <a href="" class="c">Пятый</a>
    <a href="" class="c">Шестой</a>
    <a href="" class="c">Седьмой</a>
    ....
    </div>
```

Comment: Значит без скриптов не возможно. Жаль( Спасибо все кто помог разобраться.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619955/Разделение-списка-на-несколько-колонок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам поможет свойство CSS [columns](http://htmlbook.ru/css/columns).

```
.test {
    -moz-columns: 50px 5;
    -webkit-columns: 50px 5;
    columns: 50px 5;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Учтите, это свойство появилось только в CSS3, поэтому старые браузеры его не поддерживают.

http://jsfiddle.net/RM4uL/2/

Comment: Штука классная, но оно выравнивает колонки по высоте, стараясь сделать их столько, сколько указано.

Comment: Вот в том то и дело, что нет поддержки старых браузеров. Нужно как-то универсально сделать. Но без скриптов.

Comment: Без скриптов + для старых браузеров не выйдет. Именно за этим выпускаются скрипты и новые браузеры.

Answer (score 2):

Боюсь, тут придется костылить.

```
div.wrapper
{
width:200px;
height:100px;
margin-top: 200px;
background-color:yellow;
color: #000;
/* Rotate div */
transform:rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}

div.inner
{
float: left;
width:20px;
height:10px;
background-color:blue;
margin-top: 50px;
color: #000;
/* Rotate div */
transform:rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Фишка: вы сначала разворачиваете все дивы задом-наперед, потом разворачиваете еще раз уже общий блок.
Полнейший изврат. Но должно работать как вы сказали.

N.B. Это тоже будет работать только в новых браузерах.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `display: flex;`

Вот полная документация: http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.category-list {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
.category-list li {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="category-list clearfix">
  <li class="category-item">1</li>
  <li class="category-item">2</li>
  <li class="category-item">3</li>
  <li class="category-item">4</li>
  <li class="category-item">5</li>
  <li class="category-item">6</li>
  <li class="category-item">7</li>
  <li class="category-item">8</li>
  <li class="category-item">9</li>
  <li class="category-item">10</li>
  <li class="category-item">11</li>
  <li class="category-item">12</li>
</ul>
```